# Froala editor insert at current cursor/cart position not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, froala

I want to insert some text at current position of cursor in Froala editor.

```
var editor = new FroalaEditor('#docEditor', {
    events: {
        blur() {
            this.selection.save();
        }
    },
});

function insertVariable(text) {
    editor.selection.restore();
    editor.html.insert("->" + text + "<- ", true);
}
```

Above code insert text at end of editor , I want it should insert at position of cursor in editor.

Answer (score 0):

```
const editorInstance;
var editor = new FroalaEditor('#docEditor', {
        events: {
        initialized: (e) => {
          console.warn('Editor initialized', e);
          editorInstance = e.getEditor(); // this is the editor instance.
          setEditorEvents(e.getEditor());
        },
        blur: () => {
          editorInstance.selection.save();
        }
      },
});

function insertVariable(text) {
    editorInstance.html.insert("->" + text + "<- ", true);
}
```

Try this.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).